# unable to connect expo react native app to react native debugger

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

I’ve been trying to connect my Expo React Native app to a React Native debugger so I can see network calls, but it has proved difficult.

My developer tools are running on http://localhost:19002, and the metro waiting on exp://192.168.0.198:19000.

Expo SDK: 44
React Native version: 0.68.2
React Native Debugger version: 0.12.1

My React Native Debugger for port 19000 says “waiting for client connection,” while my React Native Debugger for port 19002 says “attempting reconnection.”

On port 19002, I get the following console log:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:19002/debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

I also get this log:
bundle.js:10 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:19002/debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I look at the Network tab within the React Native Developer, I only see the following network calls: debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome

The React Native Debugger for port 19000 has no network calls or console logs.

There are indeed network calls in my app. Within the Terminal, I get the following:

`[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403]`

Let me know if you have any tips on how I can get the React Native Debugger to work on an expo app. Thanks :)